# UnitySendMessage from ios /swift

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

In android, to send a string from the App to unity is quite simple:

```
    mUnity = new UnityPlayer(this,this);
    mUnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("UnityReceiveData", "receivePlayer1Username", value);
```

With UnityReceiveData the gameObject, receivePlayer1Username the method name and value.

I saw that a similar method exists from Ios but it apparently can not be called directly on unity 2019 and later.
Based on this  structure  is a proxy needed? How to call unitysendMessage from Ios App main code?